# Parquet data to AWS Redshift slow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet

I want to insert data from S3 parquet files to Redshift.

Files in parquet comes from a process that reads `JSON` files, flatten them out, and store as parquet. To do it we use `pandas dataframes`.

To do so, I tried two different things. The first one:

```
COPY schema.table
FROM 's3://parquet/provider/A/2020/11/10/11/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::XXXX'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

It returned:

```
Invalid operation: Spectrum Scan Error
error:  Spectrum Scan Error
code:      15001
context:   Unmatched number of columns between table and file. Table columns: 54, Data columns: 41
```

I understand the error but I don't have an easy option to fix it.
If we have to do a reload from 2 months ago the file will only have for example 40 columns, because on that given data we needed just this data but table already increased to 50 columns.
So we need something automatically, or that we can specify the columns at least.

Then I applied another option which is to do a `SELECT` with `AWS Redshift Spectrum`. We know how many columns the table have using system tables, and we now the structure of the file loading again to a `Pandas dataframe`. Then I can combine both to have the same identical structure and do the insert.

It works fine but it is slow.

The select looks like:

```
SELECT fields
FROM schema.table
WHERE partition_0 = 'A'
  AND partition_1 = '2020'
  AND partition_2 = '11'
  AND partition_3 = '10'
  AND partition_4 = '11';
```

The partitions are already added as I checked using:

```
select *
from SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS
where tablename = 'table'
  and schemaname = 'schema'
  and values = '["A","2020","11","10","11"]'
limit 1;
```

I have around 170 files per hour, both in json and parquet file. The process list all files in `S3 json path`, and process them and store in `S3 parquet path`.

I don't know how to improve execution time, as the `INSERT` from `parquet` takes 2 minutes per each `partition_0` value. I tried the `select` alone to ensure its not an `INSERT` issue, and it takes 1:50 minutes. So the issue is to read data from `S3`.

If I try to select a non existent value for `partition_0` it takes again around 2 minutes, so there is some kind of problem to access data. I don't know if `partition_0` naming and others are considered as Hive partitioning format.

**Edit:**
AWS Glue Crawler table specification
[image]

Edit: Add SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY results

```
step:1
starttime: 2020-12-13 07:13:16.267437
endtime: 2020-12-13 07:13:19.644975
elapsed: 3377538
aborted: 0
external_table_name: S3 Scan schema_table
file_format: Parquet         
is_partitioned: t
is_rrscan: f
is_nested: f
s3_scanned_rows: 1132
s3_scanned_bytes: 4131968
s3query_returned_rows: 1132
s3query_returned_bytes: 346923
files: 169
files_max: 34
files_avg: 28
splits: 169
splits_max: 34
splits_avg: 28
total_split_size: 3181587
max_split_size: 30811
avg_split_size: 18825
total_retries:0
max_retries:0
max_request_duration: 360496
avg_request_duration: 172371
max_request_parallelism: 10
avg_request_parallelism: 8.4
total_slowdown_count: 0
max_slowdown_count: 0
```

**Add query checks**

Query: 37005074 (SELECT in localhost using pycharm)
Query: 37005081 (INSERT in AIRFLOW AWS ECS service)

**STL_QUERY** Shows that both queries takes around 2 min

```
select * from STL_QUERY where query=37005081 OR query=37005074 order by query asc;

Query: 37005074 2020-12-14 07:44:57.164336,2020-12-14 07:46:36.094645,0,0,24
Query: 37005081 2020-12-14 07:45:04.551428,2020-12-14 07:46:44.834257,0,0,3
```

**STL_WLM_QUERY** Shows that no queue time, all in exec time

```
select * from STL_WLM_QUERY where query=37005081 OR query=37005074;

Query: 37005074 Queue time 0 Exec time: 98924036 est_peak_mem:0
Query: 37005081 Queue time 0 Exec time: 100279214 est_peak_mem:2097152
```

**SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY** Shows that query takes 3-4 seconds in s3

```
select * from SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY where query=37005081 OR query=37005074 order by endtime desc;

Query: 37005074 2020-12-14 07:46:33.179352,2020-12-14 07:46:36.091295
Query: 37005081 2020-12-14 07:46:41.869487,2020-12-14 07:46:44.807106
```

**stl_return** Comparing min start for to max end for each query. 3-4 seconds as says `SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY`

```
select * from stl_return where query=37005081 OR query=37005074 order by query asc;

Query:37005074  2020-12-14 07:46:33.175320 2020-12-14 07:46:36.091295
Query:37005081  2020-12-14 07:46:44.817680 2020-12-14 07:46:44.832649
```

I dont understand why `SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY` shows just 3-4 seconds to run query in spectrum, but then `STL_WLM_QUERY` says the excution time is around 2 minutes as i see in my localhost and production environtments... Neither how to improve it, because `stl_return` shows that query returns few data.

**EXPLAIN**

```
XN Partition Loop  (cost=0.00..400000022.50 rows=10000000000 width=19608)
  ->  XN Seq Scan PartitionInfo of parquet.table  (cost=0.00..22.50 rows=1 width=0)
        Filter: (((partition_0)::text = 'A'::text) AND ((partition_1)::text = '2020'::text) AND ((partition_2)::text = '12'::text) AND ((partition_3)::text = '10'::text) AND ((partition_4)::text = '12'::text))
  ->  XN S3 Query Scan parquet  (cost=0.00..200000000.00 rows=10000000000 width=19608)
"        ->  S3 Seq Scan parquet.table location:""s3://parquet"" format:PARQUET  (cost=0.00..100000000.00 rows=10000000000 width=19608)"
```

**svl_query_report**

```
select * from svl_query_report where query=37005074 order by segment, step, elapsed_time, rows;
```

[image]

Comment: Why is 2 minutes too slow for you (can't you just load them overnight)? How many files do you have? How many rows does each contain? Is it just one file per partition? What is preventing it from loading multiple files at a time -- is it because historical ones have different formats? It would

Comment: @JohnRotenstein 2 minutes is slow because the process is hourly. So to load  30 differents partitions_0 values it takes one hour... And still increasing in number of partitions_0.

The rows deppends, it comes from json files in s3 that are created through kinesis. So data is around 30kb each file. We have setup 1mb or 1 minute to limit size in kinesis.

We load per file because we list all files in an s3 path, so the natural iteration is to do it per file because we have a list of it. Anyways a thing that i want to try is to join all files in a single df.

Comment: Why are you wanting to load 30 different partitions? If the data is being generated within one hour, I would suggest loading all the files in one COPY operation. This can be done by pointing Redshift to the directory containing the files, and it will also load all files in sub-directories.

Comment: I load 30 different partitions because each partition is a provider, and each one goes to his own table.

The copy operation doesnt work. As i said in the post:

If we have to do a reload from 2 months ago the file will only have for example 40 columns, because on that given data we needed just this data but table already increased to 50 columns. So we need something automatically, or that we can specify the columns at least.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in your other question you need to change your keypaths on your objects.  It is not enough to just have "A" in the keypath - it needs to be "partition_0=A".  This is how Spectrum knows that the object is or isn't in the partition.

Also you need to make sure that your objects are of reasonable size or it will be slow if you need to scan many of them.  It takes time to open each object and if you have many small objects the time to open them can be longer than the time to scan them.  This is only an issue if you need to scan many many files.

Comment: i will change the keypaths. It is just to change the name, or i have to do any other operation?

About files i already did a test that didn't worked, but could be due to the keypath. So i i will try first to add the keypath and see how it improves.

Comment: I did the changes for one of the paths, but still taking almost 2 minutes (didn't tried yet to create bigger files). Could be that just changing one path it didn't speed it up?

I just changed: 

alter table schema.table
add partition (partition_0 = 'A',
                   partition_1 = '2020',
                   partition_2 = '11',
                   partition_3 = '10',
                   partition_4 = '11')
        location 's3://parquet/provider_parquet/partition_0=A/partition_1=2020/partition_2=11/partition_3=10/partition_4=11/';

And moved files from old to this

Comment: Can you post your "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE" statement along with any partition modifiers?

Comment: I don't have an statement. I use AWS Glue Crawlers to create the table. About the partition modifiers i don't understand what do you ask for

Comment: I added the table specifications i see in aws glue crawler. 
T

Comment: Good to know.  Glue should partition the data and (I believe) it configures Redshift correctly.  This brings us to #2 - number and size of files in the partition.  Can you look at SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY for the query you are running and it will report the number of files being access by the spectrum.  It will also report the number of bytes.

Comment: Just added SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY results in main post. I don't understand why start time and end time just show 3 sec difference when query takes around 2 minutes to show results

Comment: So first thing I would want to confirm is that you are looking at the correct query.  Please confirm that this is the information for the correct query (takes 2 min) as this is a common issue.

If this is the right query it does suggest that the delays you are seeing is not time spent in Spectrum - short query time, few files scanned in S3, bytes scanned from S3.  Can you layout the query you are using and if lots of data go out the jdbc connection?  stl_return will help if a lot of data is being returned.  Have you looked at the actual execution report on the RS console for long steps?

Comment: I just added all query checks, and some conclusions comparing start and entime between localhost queries and production once! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have confirmed that query is really taking a few seconds, good. Since inserting to a table is also taking minutes it isn't the amount of data begin returned.  This leads me to look at delays in getting the query launched.  Check the difference between when you launch the query in your bench and when RS says the query starts.

If there is a difference of more than a minute I can see a few likely issues that could be causing - delays in the bench issuing the query to Redshift, WLM queue waits, or locks. Check STL_WLM_QUERY to see how long the query is queued and compare to bench time.

Comment: Just added STL_WLM_QUERY results, and tiddy up previous queries. Now i see eecution time in STL_WLM_QUERY is around 2 minutes. No queue time. But previous queries to other STL tables shows time is around 3-4 seconds...

Comment: Ok stl_wlm_query and stl_query are both indicating that the time is spent in execution.  stl_s3query is indicating that the S3 portion is fast and returning fairly small results. So looking at the query seems like where you need to look. Explain plan and svl_query_report should tell where the time is being spent in the query.

Comment: Just added them. Already looked at it before. svl_query_report shows 3 sec difference, and explain shows cost really smalls... Maybe I miss something but i don't see anything special

Comment: Looks like everything is pointing to a delay after the query is launched but before the query execution starts.  I can think of 2 things that can do this - a long compile time or locks delaying the execution.  I think to see if there is another.  You can check svl_compile but this seems unlikely.  What is going on when this query runs?  Is there something else that could be locking?  Is there any concurrent clusters configured?  How many objects are in the bucket?  thousands or millions?

Comment: There are millions of files in the bucket, and also in the specific folder that the crawlers scan to create the table I query. The table has more than 1600 columns.

I dont see the query in svl_compile.

Dont know to check if there is something that could be locking. But I run it several times in different hours, and in production it runs every hour, so i guess that at some point could be a bottlneck but not all the time

Comment: Not seeing the compile likely means that the query was pre-compiled in a previous invocation.  Locks can be a pain to figure out but if you aren't running as part of a script or other automation the events that could cause a lock wait won't repeat.  I think we are getting to the root of the issue - too many objects in the bucket.  You see S3 is an object store not a file system so you just have "bucket_name" and "key" to look up any file.  This works well for buckets with lots of objects if you know the bucket and full key but breaks down when you need to search all keys for a matching string.

Comment: Can you use the AWS CLI to list out the contents of one of the "folders" with the parquet objects?  How long does it take?  If this is on the same order as the delay you are seeing in Redshift you may have your cause.  Too many small objects.  There are solutions to this if you are willing to reorganize your S3 structure.

Comment: First I deleted some folders that were not necessary.

Then I list: aws s3 ls s3://parquet/folder/ --recursive --summarize --human-readable | grep "Total Objects" in terminal and the returns takes also minutes... 

Now I am trying to create just a single file per each subfolder, but I will also have one file per each type/year/month/day/hour. So each day 24 files * 30 days*12months*30 types=260.000 files so will be a big improvemnt.

Any ways any other improvement will be welcomed

Comment: I forgot, now, despite cleaning more than 30 extra useless folders, I have more than 11 milions files...

Comment: Bingo. Remember that there aren't "folders" in S3 - it is flat storage. Bucket and Key.  Now when the key has '/' in it things reading the bucket treat this as a separator for convenience of access - it isn't part of how the data is stored at the lowest level.  Looking up 1 key is fast because the hash is known right off.  But searching a folder is slow (in your case) because S3 has to list the entire bucket and compare the keys to the key pattern you desire.  You paths to fix are 1) fewer smaller objects & 2) split data between buckets.  You may need both.

Comment: Okei, so i understand that the contents in a bucket are all in the root of this bucket. Despite we saw it as folders. And this is why maybe I should try to have 30 buckets, one per each type if having fewer objects doenst work.

Did i understood it well?

I can't have smaller objects, in fact I have a lot because they are too small. Around 30 kb each. So i will have fewer but bigger ones.

Comment: Another way to attack this just clicked in my memory - you can use manifest files instead of "folders" in defining the external table.  This *should* mean that Redshift has all the file keys for all the objects in the table and not have to list all 11 million keys.  You will need to use manifest files with the alter table statements that configure the partitions. This is new and I haven't tried this solution with large buckets to date so please inform everyone if this addresses the issue. I believe it is the intent of manifests on external tables to address this issue (along with some others).

Comment: mm interesting, already tried manifest files when copy files from S3, but never with spectrum. Will try to find resources in internet to investigate about that:

Thanks!